# ZF2 global function to draw data from any SQL table

Tags: function, content-management-system, zend-framework2, global

Rob Allen presents a good introduction to ZF2 in his album collection tutorial at [Getting Started with Zend Framework 2](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/overview.html).  In his module, the model looks like this:

```
  // ...
  class Albums
  {
      public $id;
      public $artist;
      public $title;

      public function exchangeArray($data)
      {
          $this->id       = ( isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null );
          $this->artist   = ( isset($data['artist']) ? $data['artist'] : null );
          $this->title    = ( isset($data['title']) ? $data['title'] : null );
      }
  // ...
```

If I then go on to build a module for my Neckties collection, my model looks like this:

```
  // ...
  class Neckties
  {
      public $tieID;
      public $tieColor;
      public $tieDesigner;

      public function exchangeArray($data)
      {
          $this->tieID        = ( isset($data['tieID']) ? $data['tieID'] : null );
          $this->tieColor     = ( isset($data['tieColor']) ? $data['tieColor'] : null );
          $this->tieDesigner  = ( isset($data['tieDesigner']) ? $data['tieDesigner'] : null );
      }
  // ...
```

and for my Insect collection, my model looks like this:

```
  // ...
  class Insects
  {
      public $bugID;
      public $bugSpecies;
      public $bugLatinName;

      public function exchangeArray($data)
      {
          $this->bugID        = ( isset($data['bugID']) ? $data['bugID'] : null );
          $this->bugSpecies   = ( isset($data['bugSpecies']) ? $data['bugSpecies'] : null );
          $this->bugLatinName = ( isset($data['bugLatinName']) ? $data['bugLatinName'] : null );
      }
  // ...
```

and you can infer from this pattern what the models look like for my FancyShoelaces collection, my BathtubToys collection, my CommemorativeSpoons collection, my FoodsThatLookLikePresidents collection and so on.

Developing models like this is inefficient in two ways: 1) each time I create a model to draw data from a different table, I’m merely duplicating the same code and changing the field and variable names; and 2) whenever I change or add table fields, I have to go back and revise my ZF2 code.  Further, I am always at risk of making mistakes in my labeling or omitting whole fields altogether.

I am migrating a CMS to ZF2, and in my current project I use a global function that declares and populates variables based on the field names of whatever table that is identified via parameter:

```
  global $query_table_names;
  $query_table_names = "SELECT column_name, column_type, data_type FROM information_schema.columns ";
  $query_table_names .= "WHERE table_name = '$table_name' AND table_schema<>'information_schema'";

  $columns = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_table_names) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error());
  while ($column = mysqli_fetch_array($columns, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $column_name = $column['column_name'];
    $data_type = $column['data_type'];

    $$column_name = ( isset($data[$column_name]) ? $data[$column_name] : null );

  }
```

I’d like to create a facsimile of this method in ZF2, but as a ZF2 newbie I’m not sure how to properly write the code or where to put it.  I would appreciate any advice or direction where to find help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation of `Data Mapper` design pattern. You can have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapping) for more info on this.

`extract`method is one part of data mapper, and his counterpart is `hydrate`.

ZF2 has many classes for hydrating objects from database. You can look at `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator` folder.

You will find, for example, the [Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/ObjectProperty.php) for your use case.

[Documentation link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html)